# How to write XML file using for loop to append elements to previous element

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write an XML file in Java. I want to have a string array filled with the element names, like so: `String[] elements = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};` I want to have a for-loop that will iterate through the array and make the first element a child of the root element, the second element a child of the first, the third element a child of the second, etc.

The goal is to have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                <d>
                </d>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

This is my Java code so far:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.newDocument();
                Element root = document.createElement("root");
                document.appendChild(root);

                String[] elements = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

                for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    Element element = document.createElement(elements[i]);
                    root.appendChild(element);
                }

                TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/test.xml"));

                transformer.transform(source, result);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Right now the for-loop just appends all the elements in the array to the root, so the XML file looks like:

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
</root>
```

I would like a for-loop that makes each element a child of the previous element.

Comment: In your for-loop, what about reaffecting root to the previously created element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending each XML element to the root element and not the newly created element.

A minimal change to your code would be setting `root` to the newly created element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    Element element = document.createElement(elements[i]);
    root.appendChild(element);
    root = element; // <-- updates the root element to the newly created element
}
```

This way, each created element will be appended to the last element.

Output:

```xml
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                <d />
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Comment: Whilst that might work, I worry about changing 'root' to the non-root element!

Answer (score 2):

You are appending all of the elements to the root, not to each other.  Try this:

```
String[] elements = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

Element current = root;

for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    Element element = document.createElement(elements[i]);
    current.appendChild(element);
    current = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an element to assign the child to which always holds the previous one, like so:

```
Element previous = root; //define element to hold previous one

for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    Element element = document.createElement(elements[i]);
    previous.appendChild(element); //assighn current to previous element
    previous = element; // reassign previous for next round
}
```